# How to describe humanities students in one word

Tags: nouns, adjectives, pejorative-language

In several languages, there is a specific, usually rather derogatory word for students of the humanities. Would it be necessary to stick to 'arts students' or 'humanities students' to point out these students in English, or is it possible to describe this in a more direct and short manner? If there is such a noun, either in official or in popular vocabulary, would it be possible to also make this into a adjective - such as 'arts students' and that is such an 'artsy' thing to do but then specifically for the humanities.

Comment: It's not just one word, but it's a commonly-used phrase nonetheless: [_Would you like fries with that?_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2B"would+you+like+fries+with+that"+%2B"liberal+arts"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)

Comment: @J.R. You know there's an even shorter term; [sucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_sucker_born_every_minute).

Comment: @J.R. who likes to embed "...puns and subtle self-references into many of my answers and comments." I see the paronomastic game is afoot but did you know you were playing?  ;-)

Comment: @ThirdNews - Maybe it's contagious...

Comment: `unemployed` and `barista`

Answer (score 1):

A humanities or social sciences student can be an ***artsie*** or ***artsy***. This is a slang U.S. usage, but you'll find it here and there in [college guides](http://youngadults.about.com/od/collegelife/qt/Choosing-A-College-Major-By-Area.htm), [student newspapers](http://www.collegiatetimes.com/news/article_88434fbc-b87d-51d8-8827-cce0bb4343a7.html), [university blogs](https://blogs.wellesley.edu/admission/mgates/science-rules/), and other [works about university life](http://www.macleans.ca/education/uniandcollege/what-i-did-right/) to refer both to the fine arts or liberal arts curricula and to the students enrolled in them. I have also seen *liberal artsy*, though only as an adjective, e.g.

> liberal, artsy, [liberal artsy](http://www.thecrimson.com/column/a-dash-of-insanity/article/2013/11/26/game-undertones/) Harvard

*Artsy* (and more sneeringly, *artsy-fartsy*) overwhelmingly refers to someone with an ostentatious, affected interest in the arts and creative culture— that is, [*arty*](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=arty). Any student more literate than your garden variety comsci or pre-business major might be accused of being *artsy* in this ordinary sense for quoting Duns Scotus or expressing a mild interest in ballet.

But the word also plays off of *arts* in the sense of *liberal arts*, *arts and sciences*, *arts and humanities*, or *arts and letters*, as commonly found in the name of the unit or program in which such a student is enrolled. The *-y* or *-ie* also serves as a friendly diminutive; at my university we regularly identified ourselves as *Artsies* or *Aggies* depending on which college we were enrolled in. We also had *[Hotelies](http://www.pubs.hotelschool.cornell.edu/i/264055)*, *[HumEccies](http://www.human.cornell.edu/)*, and even [I-L-R-ies](http://prezi.com/ej8vywluefuo/top-5-misconceptions-about-ilries/), though of course these are very much institution-specific

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be necessary to stick to 'arts students' or 'humanities students' to point out these students in English, or is it possible to describe this in a more direct and short manner?

There isn't really a condensed term for "humanities students", nor is there an adjective form the phrase.

This derogatory attitude certainly exists, however, and the comments have offered up a few common jabs at liberal arts degrees. J.R.'s example is one of the most common: "Would you like fries with that?"